# If $f$ is diﬀerentiable and if $f'$ is uniformly continuous on $R$, then $g_n → f '$ uniformly on R as $n → ∞$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $g_n(x) = n[f(x + 1/n) − f(x)]$, where $f : R → R$ is a continuous function.

If $f$ is diﬀerentiable and if $f'$ is uniformly continuous on $R$, then $g_n → f '$ uniformly on R as $n → ∞$.

This question was answered earlier. But answer was not clear and nobody cared. That's why I am asking this question.

Comment: No one knows what $g_n$ is in the first sentence. Define $g_n$ first, then proceed.

Comment: edited.................................@zhw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

By the mean value theorem there is $\xi \in (x, x + 1/n)$ such that

$$|g_n(x) - f'(x)| = |n(f(x + 1/n) - f(x)) - f'(x)| = |f'(\xi) - f'(x)|$$

Now apply the uniform continuity of $f'$.

**Added Clarification**

Choose any $\epsilon > 0$. Uniform continuity of $f'$ prescribes $\delta > 0$ depending only on $\epsilon$ such that $|f'(y) - f'(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x-y| < \delta.$

Take $N(\epsilon)$ to be a positive integer with $N(\epsilon) > 1/\delta$. Consider any $n > N(\epsilon)$.  We have $|y-x| < \delta$ for every $y$ between $x$ and $x + 1/n$. By the MVT, there exists some $\xi$ between $x$ and $x + 1/n$ such that $$g_n(x) = n(f(x+1/n) - f(x)) = f'(\xi).$$

Since $|\xi-x| < \delta$, we have

$$|g_n(x) - f'(x)| = |f'(\xi) - f'(x)| < \epsilon,$$

for *any* $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and *every* $n > N(\epsilon)$, proving uniform convergence.

Comment: I did not get you. Depending on a fix epsilon greater than $0$ you will get a $\xi$..But from this $\xi$ how you are getting $n$?    actually in your answer $\xi$ depends on $n$...If I am wrong, can u please help me to get on the right track? @RRL

Comment: Given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f'(y) - f'(x) | < \epsilon$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|y-x| < \delta$.  For all $n > 1/\delta$ we have $1/n < \delta$ and since $x < \xi < x +1/n$ we have $|\xi - x| < \delta$. Hence, $|g_n(x) - f'(x)| = |f'(\xi) - f'(x)| < \epsilon$ when $n > 1/\delta$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @cmi:  I'll leave the answer as a hint -- but the comment finishes the proof of uniform convergence.,

Comment: I still can not understand.. How could you write the last line?                             How can you ensure that for $\xi$ there will be $n$? By MVT we can say here for every $n$  there exists a $\xi$. But you are claiming if $\xi$ exists we will get a $n$. How this is being possible here?@RRL

Comment: Thanks for the downvote while I prepare a response.  I am not claiming thre is an $n$ given $\xi$.  It is the other way around.

Comment: How did you write the last line?

Comment: @cmi As RRL explained in the comment: Given $\epsilon$, there exists a number $N$ (obtained as $N:=\lfloor\frac1\delta\rfloor$ from the uniform continuity of $f'$), such that for all $n>N$ and for all $x$, we have $|g_n(x)-f'(x)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Choose any $\epsilon > 0$,  uniform continuity of $f'$ prescribes a $\delta$ depending only on $\epsilon$.  Take $N(\epsilon)$ to be a positive integer with $N(\epsilon) > 1/\delta$.  Now consider any $n > N(\epsilon)$.  We have $|y-x| < \delta$ for every $y$ such that $x < y < x + 1/n$.  Now $g_n(x) = n(f(x+1/n) - f(x))$.  By the mean value theorem there must be some $\xi$ between $x$ and $x + 1/n$ such that $g_n(x) = f'(\xi)$.  Since $|\xi - x| < \delta$ we have $|f'(\xi) - f'(x)| < \epsilon$. and $|g_n(x) - f'(x)| < \epsilon$  where $x$ is arbitrary.  But $n > N$ is arbitrary So ...

Comment: Hey @RRL can u please copy paste the preceding comment in your answer?